# pricebook sharing

Tags: pricebook

We have two active pricebooks. OWD is set to "No access" on pricebook and we have extended sharing to "All internal users" on PB1 with "use". But no sharing on PB2.

When I log in with a Profile A (internal user) and click on "Add Products" under Opportunity, I get the option to choose pricebook. But when I login with a Profile B, again internal user and click on "Add Products", it chooses the default PB i.e. PB1. Shouldn't the behavior be the same if both are internal users? Is there a profile dependency on this?

Tried adding "All Internal Users" to PB2, with "View Only" option, but I still get the choose price book option.

Any options?

Thanks!